# Make a view with rectangle shape using xml definitions (drawable) in Android

Tags: android, xml, shapes

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0vP0ppNf8G3MFdBRmF5WkJEZ3c/view?usp=sharing

I want to create shape as above.
How do you create this using xml?

Comment: Please make the file publicly available

Comment: Sorry, I changed it.

Comment: you cannot do that in xml, instead use a custom **Shape** object and pass it to **ShapeDrawable**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:right="-100dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-5"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="100%">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#f9c" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```